# Is $1e-005 = 1e-5$?

Tags: notation, terminology, matlab

Totally new to Matlab, I encountered the notation $1e-005$ without proper context to guess its meaning. After googling, I found that it may represent the number $0.00001$. However, I know that $1e-5$ already denotes $0.00001$. So is 
$$
1e-005 = 1e-5?
$$

Comment: @Moo Thanks. Yes, it does. You know how I can have Matlab show the decimal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the output of `(1e-5) - (1e-005)` is `0`.

In the same way that `(005) - (5)` evaluates to `0`.

You can omit the brackets if you like.

I don't know if you can force Matlab to always explicit the decimals, as opposed to the more compact scientific notation. But you can try `format long`, see [examples here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

If you insist on decimals, maybe [one of those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149348/how-to-display-with-n-decimal-places-in-matlab) will help.

I suppose that the reason for showing the two zeros in the exponent of `1e-005` comes from the fact that the double precision number will never need a four-digit exponent: [see here](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#f2-98720). Therefore, adhering to a three-digit exponent will make a collection of such numbers look nicer / easier to read.

The existence of different possible representations of the same number is presumably a corollary of how numbers are parsed. It seems that there is no publicly available formal grammar for MATLAB, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583307/where-can-i-find-a-formal-grammar-for-matlab).

Comment: Got any idea why there exist two notationally different symbol for the same number?

Comment: @GudsonChou: see updated answer

Comment: Can you make it more specific? Do it or not according to your free will :).

Comment: @GudsonChou: see updated answer